# How to write correctly INNER JOIN in SQL via python?

Tags: python, sql, inner-join, where-clause

I have a database from https://www.imdb.com. I would like to find which directors (if any) have obtained a score higher than 9 for all their titles?

```
Crew : 'title_id', 'person_id', category, 'job', 'characters'

[('tt0000060', 'nm0005690', 'director', None, '\\N'),
('tt0000060', 'nm0005658', 'cinematographer', None, '\\N'),
('tt0000361', 'nm0349785', 'director', None, '\\N'),
('tt0000376', 'nm0466448', 'actor', None, '\\N'),
('tt0000376', 'nm0617272', 'actress', None, '["Salome"]')...

Ratings: 'title_id', 'rating', 'votes'

[('tt0000060', 7.8, 59),
('tt0000361', 8.1, 10),
('tt0000376', 7.8, 6),
('tt0000417', 8.2, 38836),
('tt0000505', 8.1, 11),
('tt0000738', 7.8, 11)...
```

My code is:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, inspect
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///newIMDB.db')
inspector = inspect(engine)
print(inspector.get_table_names()) #['crew', 'episodes', 'people', 'ratings', 'titles']
conn = engine.connect()

stmt = text ("SELECT category,rating FROM(SELECT * FROM crew INNER JOIN ratings
ON crew.title_id = ratings.title_id)  
WHERE category=director AND  rating  > 9 LIMIT 10;" )

result = conn.execute(stmt)
result.fetchall()
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I can notice here is your query is spanning across multiple lines. And for that you have used one time double quotes (i.e., "). But for multiple line strings in python you need to use 3 times quotes.
So can you try with something like...

```
stmt = text ("""SELECT category,rating FROM(SELECT * FROM crew 
INNER JOIN ratings
ON crew.title_id = ratings.title_id)  
WHERE category='director' AND  rating  > 9 LIMIT 10;""" )
```

There are also other ways to write strings spanning multiple lines as well. Rest of the ways are on you to find out!!!

Yes also any string literal(Like 'director') inside the query needs to be quoted.
(Thank you [slothrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765091/slothrop) for pointing this out)

Comment: 'director' needs to be enclosed in its own quotes too, since it is a string literal inside the query